# Incomplete Tile Package from ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, tile-package

I am running a tile package, but when it finishes the bottom third of the tile is not visible. The only thing that has changed recently is that I have upgraded from version 10.4 to 10.5. A co-worker with version 10.5 runs the same tile on his machine with the same .mdx that I am using and gets a complete tile.

Any ideas on what may be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem and it was with the message window that opens after clicking on the Analyze button. Prior to version 10.5 I would always click on the Share button after reviewing the results of the analyze. Apparently in 10.5 you need to close that window first before clicking the Share button.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run the tile package through the 'Share-as' option or using the 'Create Map Tile Package' tool? I had the same issue with the former, but found it was resolved by using the 'Create Map Tile Package' tool.